# How can I use current_user from controller context and use it in my Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class with the following code:

```
class EventLog::EventLogBuilder

  def initialize(event, params={})
    @action      = event
    @user_id     = params.fetch(:user_id) { current_user.id }
  end

  def save
    MyModel.create(action: @action, user_id: @user_id)
  end
end
```

When I call the function from within my home controller:

```
EventLog::EventLogBuilder.new(:logout).save
```

I'm getting an error as I can't access current_user from controller:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<EventLog::EventLogBuilder:0x007f9cc2981d70>
```

How can I get current_user from the controller context? I don't wanna pass current_user to EventLogBuilder class and I don't want to create a wrapper method in application_controller.rb and pass the current_user.

Comment: “I don't wanna pass current_user to EventLogBuilder class” except this is exactly what you should do. You don’t expect params to magically appear in the model layer, why should current_user be any different?

Comment: Because I want to use EventLogBuilder from within my controllers all the time and no need to send extra param everytime. I just want something simple to read the data from the caller context. Something like CallingController.instance_eval{current_user}. I'm not sure how to do that but I'm pretty sure there is a way.

Comment: If you want access to the current user just pass it into the constructor. If you want to make it less verbose across controllers put it in the ApplicationController. Anything else is overly complex and will be confusing to anyone trying to read your code.

Comment: @EkiEqbal check this link once it might be useful to you, http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models

Comment: Thanks Alex. I agree. As I just tried some workaround by passing the current user object from controllers to models, but it is too ugly. What you recommend here? To close this or to delete the post??

Comment: @Alex.Bullard, your help is highly appreciated. Can you recommend what to do with this question? as I have to leave it or is it better to close it or even delete it?